# Ansible template strange error appears while using conditional rendering

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this ansible role

```
---

- name: render motd template
  template:
    src: motd.j2
    dest: /etc/motd
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
```

and this template in `motd.j2`

```
Welcome to {{inventory_hostname}}!
{{if ansible_distribution_major_version == 'NA'}}
There is {{ansible_distribution}}!
{{else}}
There is {{ansible_distribution}} {{ansible_distribution_major_version}}!
{{endif}}
```

When i try to execute this role, i have this error:

```
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: 
expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'.
```

What is wrong here?

If i use template

```
Welcome to {{ inventory_hostname }}!
There is {{ansible_distribution}} {{ansible_distribution_major_version}}!
```

all works as expected.
I assume there is error with `if` conditional

Comment: Please read Jinja2 documentation. You are confusing variable output and expressions. The latter are enclosed with different signs => `{% if some_condition %}`, `{% else %}`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like this fixed task to render template properly, jinja2 has unusual different delimeters to variable output (`{{ }}`) and to conditional rendering commands (`{% %}`):

```
Welcome to {{ inventory_hostname }}!
{% if ansible_distribution_major_version == 'NA' %}
There is {{ ansible_distribution }}!
{% else %}
There is {{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}!
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is actually unusual about this ? Several other template engines have the same kind of syntax to separate expressions and statements.